# Can I wish someone on new home as " my cordial wishes to your family on new home"

Tags: adverbs

I would like to wish my boss on her new home. Is the below statement correct?

> *My cordial wishes to your family on new home*

Comment: "My cordial wishes to your family on your new home" would be closer to correct, though the other suggestions are better.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would fit better

> **"Congratulations on your new home. May it always be filled with happiness."**

or, to keep some of your words

> **"My best wishes to you and your family at your new home."**

Answer (score 0):

In the US, we use "Best Wishes (on, or, in) your new home!" (Even if it's not a complete or technically correct sentence) I guess it's kind of idiomatic.